# VS 2008 debugger displays integers in hex

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, hex

For some reason my Visual Studio debugger has started to show me my integers in Hex. I am programming ASP.net using C#.
Does anyone have an idea how can I convince the debugger to display integers in decimal again?

Thanks a lot,
Assaf.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click the Hex button on the Debug toolbar.  (Or in the context menu of the Watch, Locals, or Autos windows)

Comment: Man, I would have never find it. Thanks a million.
Assaf.